# EWS fetch mails having specified subject line

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

How can I specify the `SearchFilter` with Java EWS library to fetch mails containing defined subject line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean the library created by Microsoft, here is an example directly from the *Getting started with EWS Java API.rtf* included in the download:

```
public void findItems()
{
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
view.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject,
        ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));


FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
LogicalOperator.Or, new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "EWS"), 
new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "API")),view);

System.out.println("Total number of items found: " + findResults.getTotalCount());

for (Item item : findResults)
    {
            System.out.println(item.getSubject());
            System.out.println(item.getBody());
            // Do something with the item.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine .. Thanks for help. Though I am trying for not having case sensitive . If you are aware pls let me know.

Comment: Hello, I have problems to sort the items when use the findItems() method. The way that you use in the previous answer works?

Comment: If in case the subject line has special characters like ÿ etc, the find items won't retrieve anything.